# ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment while using "+="

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, referenceerror

I'm trying to solve this following kata on Codewars: [Strip Comments](https://www.codewars.com/kata/strip-comments).
I think this is pretty legit code, but I'm getting the following error:

> ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

for this part: `reg += "\\" += item += "|";` (line 6)

Here is my code:

```
function solution(input, markers) {
  var arr = input.split("\n");
  var reg = "(";
  markers.forEach(function(item, index){
  if (!(index == markers.length)){
  reg += "\\" += item += "|";
  } else {reg += "\\" += item += ")";}
  })
  reg += ".*";
  var regex = new RegExp(reg);
  arr.forEach(function(item){
  item.replace(regex, "");
  })
  var ret = arr.toString();
  ret.replace(/\,/g, "\n");
  return ret;
};
```

Comment: You can not use `+=` this way. Quote MDN: _“An assignment operator assigns a value to its left operand based on the value of its right operand.”_ `"\\"` is not a thing that you could assign a new value to, it is a text literal, not a variable.

Comment: streamlined your code a bit: `function solution(input, markers) { var regex = new RegExp("(" + markers.map(item => "\\" + item).join("|") + ").*"); return input.split("\n").map(item => item.replace(regex, "")).join("\n") }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+=` cannot be used between strings. Concatenate items using `+`

```js
function solution(input, markers) {
    var arr = input.split("\n");
    var reg = "(";
    markers.forEach(function(item, index){
    if (!(index == markers.length)){
    reg += "\\" + item + "|";
    } else {reg += "\\" + item + ")";}
    })
    reg += ".*";
    var regex = new RegExp(reg);
    arr.forEach(function(item){
    item.replace(regex, "");
    })
    var ret = arr.toString();
    ret.replace(/\,/g, "\n");
    return ret;
  };
```

Comment: Thank you! That really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

`a += b` does two things:

1. It combines its left operand (`a`) with its right (`b`). (With strings, "combines" means "concatenates" [joins together]. With numbers, it means "adds".)
2. It puts the result of (1) into its left operand (`a`).

That means that what's on the left of it has to be something you can change the value of. You can't change the value of a string literal, it isn't assignable. So the problem is her:

```
reg += "\\" += item += "|";
// ---------^^------^^
```

The first `+=` there is fine, it's the second two that are problematic. The second one tries to assign back to the expression `reg += "\\"`, which it can't.

You just wanted `+` there:

```
reg += "\\" + item + "|";
// ---------^------^
```

---

I suggest working through a basic JavaScript book and/or tutorials from reputable sources. When you're not sure what an operator does, I suggest looking it up [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript).